# Context menu preview provider with storyboard segues

Tags: ios, uikit, contextmenu, ios13

In my storyboard, I have a table view controller with static cells, each performing a segue to present view controllers.

Until now, it was possible to enable Peek and Pop support in the storyboard, and it would implement all the legacy API for that.

There doesn't appear to be such an option right now for context menus.

My question is, is it possible to somehow obtain the controller from the segue on demand, so that I can return it by the `UIContextMenuContentPreviewProvider`? Any other suggestions (other than changing the static cells in the storyboard) are welcome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Solved* this with private API, but **this should not be used**! **For educational purposes only!**

I gave each cell and the segue the same identifier. Then using private APIs, I instantiate the destination controller for the segue and return that as the preview.

Let's declare some private APIs:

```
@interface UIViewController ()

- (id)_segueTemplateWithIdentifier:(id)arg1;

@end

@interface NSObject ()

- (id)instantiateOrFindDestinationViewControllerWithSender:(id)arg1;

@end
```

Then tie it together in the implementation:

```
@implementation DemoGalleryController

- (nullable UIContextMenuConfiguration *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView contextMenuConfigurationForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath point:(CGPoint)point API_AVAILABLE(ios(13.0))
{
    return [UIContextMenuConfiguration configurationWithIdentifier:@"Preview" previewProvider:^ UIViewController* {
        NSString* cellIdentifier = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath].reuseIdentifier;
        id segueTemplate = [self _segueTemplateWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
        return [segueTemplate instantiateOrFindDestinationViewControllerWithSender:self];;
    } actionProvider:nil];
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willPerformPreviewActionForMenuWithConfiguration:(UIContextMenuConfiguration *)configuration animator:(id<UIContextMenuInteractionCommitAnimating>)animator API_AVAILABLE(ios(13.0))
{
    UIViewController* vc = animator.previewViewController;

    [animator addCompletion:^{
        [self presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:nil];
    }];
}

@end
```